# How do I know the most efficient image encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I am familiar with any algorithm that is based on the number of bits in a key (n-bit) and how to restore a key, such as the Discrete Logarithm Problem or Factorization. 
When I use any algorithm for encrypting and decrypting images, such as RSA, how can I estimate this algorithm's security and work efficiently with image encryption.

Comment: The encryption algorithms operate on binary data, they don't care about the type( well there is format-preserving encryption that has a special formulation for numbers, etc..) What is your aim? Who will access these files? Why don't you just a Veracrpt volume to store them? RSA or any public key cryptosystem is not preferred to encrypt data, it is preferred for signature and key encapsulation...

Answer (score 1):

> I am familiar with any algorithm that is based on the number of bits in a key (n-bit) and how to restore a key, such as the Discrete Logarithm Problem or Factorization.

There are hundreds if not thousands of encryption algorithms. What you are naming are hard problems that we use to build algorithms such as Diffie-Hellman which uses the DLP, or RSA which relies on the fact that it is hard to factor the modulus (the RSA problem).

> When I use any algorithm for encrypting and decrypting images, such as RSA

Nobody uses RSA directly to encrypt images. And modern encryption algorithms operate on bits / bytes, which can represent any kind of "message". Although RSA itself operates on numbers, the PKCS#1 specifications - that define two secure ways of padding for encryption - will require the message to consist of bytes.

> how can I estimate this algorithm's security and work efficiently with image encryption.

You can look at [keylength.com](https://keylength.com) for recommendations of for the key size and the relative security or strength (also usually shown in bits) that a particular key size can offer.

As for efficiency, usually key encapsulation is used to encrypt a random symmetric data key which can then encrypt the image. This way of combining asymmetric and symmetric algorithms is called [a hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Generally symmetric algorithms are much faster and use less overhead to encrypt data.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning Naor-Shamir "[Visual Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_cryptography)", which is image-specific and about as interesting as any other One-Time Pad system (not terribly useful in practice, but not completely uninteresting either).

Comment: What tools are used to evaluate algorithm efficacy?
Is correlation coefficient  used for this purpose?
Or what????